# Permission to see org ID?

Tags: permissions, partner-wsdl

Is there a permission that controls if a user can see the organization ID?

I'm trying to support a 3rd party developer.  All they sent me was this image and said that they need the org ID not to be null.  I'm assuming they are calling the partner API getUserInfo method.

[image]

I know this is kind of vague, but I'm just wondering if anyone has any insight as to why that value is not getting returned.  Maybe its a permission on the user or profile?

Comment: A shot in the dark, how about "View Setup Data"? I remember having to go through this once but cannot remember what solved it. My google foo is failing me at the moment

Comment: @Eric that didn't seem to fix it.  If you remember please let me know!  I just tried testing with the admin profile and it still doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a permission for that, but could be an api version. I ran into this in a similar project and they were somehow using the partner v2.5 endpoint which did not include an org id at that point. Using the correct endpoint addressed the issue.